# Javascript return object inside for loopHi guy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop, object

Could anybody guide me on how to return an object inside a for loop please? It currently exits at the first iteration, I understand that return should not be used here, but unsure of what I should be using.

```
const allOrders = orderTotals && orderTotals.map((orders) => {
    
    let obj = orders['totals']
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        return {
            x: key,
            y: obj[key].orders,
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you

--

EDIT

Here's the json, I'm trying to loop over the totals to get the key (X) value and orders (y) value, so I can create a chart.

```
{
    "total_sales": "1410.37",
    "net_sales": "1404.47",
    "average_sales": "117.04",
    "total_orders": 66,
    "total_items": 65,
    "total_tax": "0.00",
    "total_shipping": "5.90",
    "total_refunds": 48.67999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875,
    "total_discount": "60.25",
    "totals_grouped_by": "month",
    "totals": {
        "2020-01": {
            "sales": "0.00",
            "orders": 0,
            "items": 0,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "0.00",
            "customers": 0
        },
        "2020-02": {
            "sales": "75.37",
            "orders": 3,
            "items": 3,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "3.00",
            "customers": 2
        },
        "2020-03": {
            "sales": "55.23",
            "orders": 2,
            "items": 2,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "5.75",
            "customers": 1
        },
        "2020-04": {
            "sales": "0.00",
            "orders": 0,
            "items": 0,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "0.00",
            "customers": 2
        },
        "2020-05": {
            "sales": "71.37",
            "orders": 2,
            "items": 2,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "4.60",
            "customers": 1
        },
        "2020-06": {
            "sales": "96.21",
            "orders": 5,
            "items": 5,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "5.75",
            "customers": 0
        },
        "2020-07": {
            "sales": "85.86",
            "orders": 4,
            "items": 4,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "5.90",
            "discount": "0.00",
            "customers": 4
        },
        "2020-08": {
            "sales": "187.77",
            "orders": 8,
            "items": 8,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "5.75",
            "customers": 1
        },
        "2020-09": {
            "sales": "112.35",
            "orders": 5,
            "items": 5,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "4.60",
            "customers": 2
        },
        "2020-10": {
            "sales": "302.08",
            "orders": 14,
            "items": 14,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "2.80",
            "customers": 4
        },
        "2020-11": {
            "sales": "442.82",
            "orders": 22,
            "items": 21,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "6.00",
            "customers": 10
        },
        "2020-12": {
            "sales": "29.99",
            "orders": 1,
            "items": 1,
            "tax": "0.00",
            "shipping": "0.00",
            "discount": "0.00",
            "customers": 0
        }
    },
    "total_customers": 27,
    "_links": {
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "/wp-json/wc/v3/reports"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the original object & the output object that you are trying to get?

Comment: Yes of course, I've just added the original json. Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense - mapping maps on to the other, yet you are looping through and trying to 'return' each? What do you expect the outcome to be? Theres only _one_ output for this method, so you need to consolidate into one object or array.

Comment: @Lee what's the desired output object that you're looking for?

Comment: Yes sorry new to JS, I basically want to iterate over "totals" returning the key (Date) and the orders value. I can't map as it isn't an array, so not sure how to get these values as the key will change I assume I shouldn't use orders['totals']['2020-03'] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
const chartData = Object.entries(data['totals']).map(([date, values]) => {
    return {x: date, y: values.orders}
  })
```

Where `data` is JSON you're trying to loop over.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed